# Double click on window title bar only maximizes window height - Can it be disabled?

Tags: windows-7

As soon as I started using Windows 7, I wondered why the "maximize window", performed with a double click on title bar "sometimes only maxes height".

After some (unsuccessful) googling, and several tests on my computer, it appears the behaviour is : ***if you click on the upper part of the title bar, only height will be maximized***. (else, both dimensions will be)

Now that I noticed the cause, I probably will start getting used to click only on the bottom of the bar, but I really can't find any use to such a feature.

Regularly stumbling upon such a basic action, while it doesn't spend much time, becomes a serious annoyance over time.

Does anyone know a way to **disable** this behaviour ?

Comment: My behavior is the opposite.

Answer (score 1):

Long story short: **You can't**

I've actually searched for a way to disable this functionality completely (not just the maximize window height) but I have turned up empty.

Your best bet would be third party software, but I've been unable to find any that can do it.

---

**Now,** This may just be supplemental information but when you doubleclick once your cursor changes to an `I` then it will only maximize height. If you doubleclick anywhere else, it will fully maximize. I just want to clarify for you and/or anyone else reading.

[image]

Comment: I'm afraid you're right, but I don't lose hope yet that some obscure and unknown registry key may exist for this.
About the cursor change, I noticed it when I tested with notepad, indeed, but applications with custom cursors don't reflect this, which doesn't help much making things clear.

Comment: This is apparently a default behavior in previous version of Windows that Win 10 did not retain, as I am currently seeking to turn it back on... it's not technically maximizing to the monitor - it's maximizing to the desktop height, which in my case spans vertically across both extended monitors, which is what I actually want. Edge click extends across the desktop in that direction, Normal Pointer click maximizes the window to the monitor showing the greatest amount of the window that was clicked.